# Kdb evaluate a function on a field separately for every row

Tags: kdb

I am trying to select the description column from a table. The column contains strings however they have all been enlisted, so they are actually 1-element lists containing a string.

I have tried to undo the enlist by extracting element 0. For example:

```
table:([] id: 1 2 3; name:("Alice"; "Bob"; "Fred"); description: (enlist "wibble"; enlist "something"; enlist "hello"))
select description 0 from table
```

This produces

```
x       
--------
"wibble"
```

A 1 row table is not what I want. I want the expression evaluated for every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use (see http://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#310-elided-indices)

```
q)select description[;0] from table
x
-----------
"wibble"
"something"
"hello"
```

but you lose the column name unless you manually rename it. Instead (in this case) you can use

```
q)select first each description from table
description
-----------
"wibble"
"something"
"hello"
```

Comment: Ok so it was the each keyword I was missing to avoid it behaving like an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use ***select description from table*** in this instance?  as you state every element of description is a single element list

```
q)select description from table
description
-----------
"wibble"   
"something"
"hello"    
q)

q)\t do[10000;select first each description from table]
66

q)\t do[10000;select description[;0] from table]
63

q)\t do[10000;select description from table]
9

q)a:select first each description from table
q)b:select description[;0] from table
q)c:select description from table

q)type each c
99 99 99h

q)type each b
99 99 99h

q)type each a
99 99 99h
```

Comment: Hi Michael, you might want to take a look at the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). A little editing can go a long way in adding clarity to your answers. Hope you don't mind my suggestion.

Comment: 'select description from table' and 'select first each description from table' produce answers with different types. Have a look at the 'meta' of the resulting tables to see this more clearly.

Comment: Both are not equal . why?  Ex: "abc"  is not equal to (enlist "abc"). Same scenario is there for 'b' and 'c'. So in 'b' you have each value as string(char  list) while in 'c' each value is list of string (like list of list) because it is enlist (string).

Comment: As @user3576050 and Rahul said, a and c are different even though the q terminal shows them in the same way (this is a small quirk of q - sometimes what you see in the terminal is not always what you get). You can see the difference by looking at "0N!a;" and "0N!c;"

Comment: Makes sense guys, can see the difference now using meta & 0N!